# Private or Public TFS Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, octopus-deploy

I'm using octopack to pack my project into nuget packages for octopus deploy.  I do not want to run octopack for a private build.  How can I tell inside my TFS Build workflow if the current build is private or public?

Comment: So it looks like `BuildDetail.BuildNumber.Contains("_")` works.  But it seems a little smelly.  If you have a better way, let me know.

Answer (score 1):

If I were you:

1. Edit the current build definition template to add a new boolean property (let's say Private Build). 
   To do this, locate the Metadata argument in your XAML file and click edit, add your parameter and you can specify the visibility for your parameter
2. Add 2 different build definitions one for private and the other for public. Private will have the "PrivateBuild" true and other one will have it as false.
3. Read this property within your workflow and decide whether you have to run Octopack or not.